Object Selection for Script
I have a simple script that converts instances (makes them real) and then joins them all together. It replaces the need to do several individual steps with one click.
What I'm trying to do is...
I want to point an object to my script and have the script update automatically based on the object selected from a list in the UI.
Currently the script looks for "Branch.001" I want to be able to edit the "Branch" part of the script on the fly whilst keeping the .001.
Current script...
import bpy

# Make instances real
bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()

# Check if the object named "Branch.001" exists
if "Branch.001" in bpy.data.objects:
# Set the object named "Branch.001" as the active object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["Branch.001"]

#Object - Data
bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=True, obdata=True, material=False, 
animation=False)

# Join
bpy.ops.object.join()

# Clear selection
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Check for an object named "Branch.001" and select it
branch_obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Branch.001")
if branch_obj:
    branch_obj.select_set(True)

# Check for an object named "tree" and select it
tree_obj = bpy.data.objects.get("tree")
if tree_obj:
    tree_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = tree_obj

# Join
bpy.ops.object.join()

The script/addon is used to convert and join custom leaves (or branches with leaves) when using the "Sapling Tree" addon that ships with Blender. After making the tree and assigning the custom leaves you end up with a trunk and branches and a bunch of instanced leaves.
The trunk has to be converted to a mesh and the uv's need to be rotated -90°, that part of my script works perfectly.
The leaf instances need to be converted to geometry or "made real", when this happens hundreds of individual leaves show up in the outliner and are highlighted. One of those leaves has to be made "active" by ctrl clicking on it keeping the rest highlighted so that they can be set to single user (otherwise every leaf will get all the leaves attached to it when joined)...then with them still selected they are joined together to make one object. That joined leaves object is then joined to the trunk to make the final tree.
There are many tedious steps involved when doing this (many iterations of trees are made)...I have automated all those steps with a few clicks. The custom leaf or branch needs to be renamed to "Branch" for the script to work...I have many custom leaves and branches that I would like to be able to select without having to rename them to "Branch".
I'd like to choose a leaf, select it or copy its name and somehow insert it into the script automatically, rather than rename my leaves back and forth every time I choose a different one to instance. Essentially editing the script rather than the custom object in a simple UI

It's usual to perform some operations with selected objects or the active object. Why do you want to type object's name or select it from a list when you could do that in all the ways for selecting an object in Blender that already exist like in the viewport or the outliner? Why wouldn't it work for you to use the active object?

I'll edit my original post with more information.

Have you considered that you are increasing the memory used for leaves significantly by not reusing the geometry of one leaf?

You could have a pointer property that points to some object in the UI. It needs to be stored somewhere like scene or another object... Not sure if this is not an XY problem. It would be better to make it work the way things work in Blender. You usually select things and then run an operator. Is it possible for you to put the workflow into this kind of scenario where you select your object, then the tree and run an operation?

Martynas, that what I'm talking about...pointing an object from the outliner in the scene to my script with the addition of .001 to it. The .001 NEEDS to be there as a suffix to the selected object name.

I mean PointerProperty, you can add them to panels, but I doubt that's the best way to do it so I hesitate to provide it as the answer. I think best thing to do would be to perform operation on selected objects that you select in the viewport or Outliner if possible. It would probably be easier to use if possible.

Here is the solution for my question. This script takes a selected object and stores the name of that object as well as adding .001 to it, to later be used to make the instances real, single user and joining.
This script is specifically made to use custom leaves (Dupliverts) with the "Sapling Tree Gen" addon that comes with Blender...it speeds up the finalizing of the tree as there are many steps to do so.
I want to make it clear, the script was made using ChatGPT and some really basic scripting knowledge.
Here is the script.
import bpy

# Get the selected object
selected_obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Ensure an object is selected
if selected_obj is None:
  print("No object selected.")
else:
# Original name of the selected object
original_name = selected_obj.name

# Create the new name with suffix .001
Objectvar = original_name + ".001"    
    
# Check if an object named 'leaves' exists in the scene
if 'leaves' in bpy.data.objects:
    # Deselect all objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    # Select the object named 'leaves'
    leaves_obj = bpy.data.objects['leaves']
    leaves_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = leaves_obj
    
    # Apply 'Make Instances Real'
    bpy.ops.object.duplicates_make_real()
                
    # Check if an object with the name Objectvar exists
    if Objectvar in bpy.data.objects:
                    
        # Select the object with the new name
        Objectvar_obj = bpy.data.objects[Objectvar]
        Objectvar_obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = Objectvar_obj
        
        #Object - Data
        bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=True, obdata=True, material=False, animation=False)        
                    
        # Join selected objects
        bpy.ops.object.join()
                                
        # Deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        
        # Check if Objectvar exists
        if Objectvar in bpy.data.objects:
            # Select Objectvar
            Objectvar_obj = bpy.data.objects[Objectvar]
            Objectvar_obj.select_set(True)
            
            # Check if an object named 'tree' exists in the scene
            if 'tree' in bpy.data.objects:
                # Select the object named 'tree'
                tree_obj = bpy.data.objects['tree']
                tree_obj.select_set(True)
                
                # Join the 'Objectvar' and 'tree' objects
                bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = tree_obj
                bpy.ops.object.join()
                
        # Clear selection
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
           

        # Check for an object named "leaves" and select it
        leaves_obj = bpy.data.objects.get("leaves")
        if leaves_obj:
            leaves_obj.select_set(True)
             
        # Delete leaves object   
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)

        # Check if an object named 'tree' exists in the scene
        if 'tree' in bpy.data.objects:
            # Get the object named 'tree'
            tree_obj = bpy.data.objects['tree']
            
            # Rename the object to 'Tree_Done'
            tree_obj.name = "Tree_Done"

        # Purge orphan data    
        bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(do_local_ids=True, do_linked_ids=True, do_recursive=True) 

After the tree is done and you exit out of the Sapling addon, you can select the "Custom leaf" which is the child of the "leaves (instance)" which is a child of the "tree" and run the script. I made a UI in Serpens to make that easier.


I am glad it was helpful(consider up-voting and/or accepting the answer), but this is not a regular forum. The site has question and answer format and you just posted a reply as an answer. It's really more than OK to post answers to your own questions to leave the solutions you come up with for people facing similar issues in the future, but your post doesn't really describe a specific solution in detail so it doesn't seem like it could be considered to be an answer.

Oh ok...that makes sense as I didn't really post the actual solution in any real detail. I answered my own question to be able to add an image, I'm not super familiar with this forum. If you feel this post/question might be confusing to others, I don't mind removing it. Either way, thank you for guiding me in the right direction, this was such a difficult thing to explain...a video would have made it so much easier. Let me know if I should remove this post/question?

I think it makes sense to remove it, it will just likely get removed by the community eventually anyway.

Or, of course you could edit it and add a more detailed solution you ended up with if you think it could be useful for someone else and were willing to share it and of course were willing to spend time on that. This seems really specific though and might be hard to apply outside this quite specific context, but in general that's a nice thing to consider if possible.

I edited my answer with the actual solution to my original question...I hope it helps others.

import bpy


class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.object, "my_object")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.types.Object.my_object = bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name = "Object",
        description = "Select Object",
        type = bpy.types.Object
        )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    del bpy.types.Object.my_object


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

This uses property attached to each object.

You could store it somewhere else like the scene data block for example. Or should I say the Scene type. It's made in the register function:
bpy.types.Object.my_object = bpy.props.PointerProperty(...

so you could change it to:
bpy.types.Scene.my_object = bpy.props.PointerProperty(...

then you have to access it from scene.my_object so you have to change the panel as well. And it will live attached to those types of datablocks whatever you choose, so you can access them from context bpy.context.object.my_object or bpy.context.scene.my_object
The property values will be saved with the file, but the script needs to run for them to be accessible, but that's how it works if it's an add-on.

If you could avoid this whole thing and just select the object and then the active object and get your object from selection it might be easier and faster to use. I still don't understand the whole workflow fully and if that's possible though.

You don't need to attach it to a type, but could just attach it as custom property as well, it's popular to save stuff to bpy.context.window_manager from add-ons for example.
